# confusion in installing pear mail package

Tags: php

I am very new to php, I want to send mail using SMTP, so I think pear is better. I am using php version 5.3, and I found somewhere that pear comes pre installed in php 5.3, so I am getting this script for using pear mail:

```
<?php require_once "Mail.php";  
$from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>"; 
$to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>"; 
$subject = "Hi!"; $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
```

My question is that what is mail.php, what folders I have to include ? I have downloaded pear 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look to [SWIFT](http://swiftmailer.org/). Its much easier.

Otherwise why you don't use the `mail` function from PHP? It does the same like to try in your example and you don't need PEAR.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php